# regex matches all the html tags with two characters or more but ul and ol and the list items inside it

Tags: javascript, regex

ie.

> a b i u ol ul li

tag does not match but

> br

and any other tag matches.

Thanks in advance.

The regex i got atm is

> /<([a-zA-Z]{2,})\b[^>]*>/g

which does not satisfy not matching ul and ol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you want (it will only match open tag, by the way, since I mimic what you have):

```
/<\s*(?![uo]l\b)([a-zA-Z]{2,})\s*>/g
```

I allow optional space after `<` and before `>`.

I use negative look ahead `(?![uo]l\b)` to check the tag is not either `ul` or `ol`. I throw in a word boundary check `\b` to make sure it is not part of some user-defined tag.

I assume the tag name contains only English alphabet. You can modify the regex if this assumption does not hold.

Comment: I'm guessing this should match <h1> <h2> and so on which it currently doesn't

Comment: @JayGilfor I left heading tags off on purpose. Thanks for the concern.